# Django-tastypie -- how to generate customized xml

Tags: tastypie

I have ModelResource in tastypie for a Simple Model that has an id and a name.

The XML output is shown below. But I would like to use my model name in place of "object". I seem to endlessly struggle on how to solve this -- any quick help on this? Thanks a million-- really!

```
<response>
  <objects type="list">
    <object>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>foo1</name>
      <resource_uri> blah </resource_uri>
    </object>
    <object>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>foo2</name>
      <resource_uri> blah </resource_uri>
    </object>
  </objects>
</response>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try overloading the "alter_list_data_to_serialize(...)" method of the Resource class. As the docstring says:

> A hook to alter list data just before it gets serialized & sent to the user.
>
> Useful for restructuring/renaming aspects of the what's going to be sent.

So that's the place when you change the "data" which soon after gets transformed into XML and sent to the user.

Something like this should get you going:

```
def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
    #self.object_class.lower() is the name you'd like instead of "objects"
    data = { self.object_class.lower() : [ element for element in data[ 'objects' ] ] }
    return data
```

I haven't tested this, but I'm using this method to alter how my responses look succesfully.

Comment: Hmm - this seems like a fairly heavyweight solution, in that you have to pull out all the objects from the DB and then extract the ID. It would seem preferable to be able to do this ahead of time so that we only pull the ID.

Comment: I think it doesn't pull anything extra. This method is called after the appropriate dataset is pulled from the DB by Tastypie (and stored in `data`). So the only extra overhead is the `dict` creation, but this can't be avoided if something is to be changed. Also OP asked to change the XML structure, but to include all attributes, so this answers his/her question. Pulling only a subset of object attributes is a different story.

Comment: Yes - My comment had to do with getting a subset of attrs, which, as you pointed out, is another story. :)